# Redshift: General Solution for Sorting List of Columns' Values

Tags: list, sorting, amazon-redshift

I had a classic Redshift interview question that got me thinking about how to generalize the solution.

Question:
"Given a table calls like:

| rowid | callerid | receiverid | callduration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 456 | 1 |
| 2 | 456 | 123 | 5 |
| 3 | 123 | 456 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

... etc, please write a query to return average call duration per pair."

As you know, the points of the question are first to see if you will ask whether the callerid, receiverid pair order matters. **Assume the answer for this post is no.** Then the point is to see if you can write a query that treats for ex. "123, 456" and "456, 123" the same way.

The easiest way is probably using GREATEST AND LEAST to force an order on the two columns.  I think you can also write a headache-inducing union all with antijoins in which receiverid is aliased as callerid and vice-versa.

**My question to others**: is there a generalizable solution to transform a list of values **across >2 columns?**.

I'm imagining something like:
Say instead of 2 id columns (callerid and receiverid) you had 3 columns id1, id2, id3 with values 123,789,456 respectively.

Step 1: create a column (an array, or perhaps a concatenation) that contains the delimited values--> [123,789,456] or 123|789|456.
Step 2: sort the delimited values into new column, e.g. --> [123,789,456] --> [123,456,789]

Can you get that done in Redshift?  I could do the piped list or maybe the array for step 1, but I'm not aware of a sorting solution for step 2.

The value of this would be that extends the sorting ability beyond 2 columns (as with least, greatest), without a lot of headache.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Redshift can't sort an array. You have to unnest, order it, then turn it back to an array and compare using something like a hash. But overall you're asking how to code around a bad data model.

Comment: Thank you @dfundako I will take this as the answer to the question, since you've basically said "no, you can't do that".  However I don't see a way to give you credit for the answer.  I haven't used SO in ages and I expected there to be a button or something.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.
You need to combine two columns(**array** function) and after it unnest them and group(**listagg**) them in correct order

Code

```sql
with temp as (select 1 as row_id, 1 as caller_id, 2 as receiver_id
              union
              select 2, 2, 1
              union
              select 3, 1, 3),
     concatted as (select row_id, array(caller_id, receiver_id) as ids
                   from temp)
select row_id, listagg(id::varchar) within group (order by id) as concat_ids
from concatted as c,
     c.ids as id
group by row_id
order by row_id;
```

Input

| row_id | caller_id | receiver_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

Output

| row_id | concat_ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 13 |

Comment: I'm sorry -- I'll have to retract my designation of this as the question.  The OP was about being able to sort values per row without having to use unions, now that I think more about it.  Apologies for the retraction.